# What is the difference between UnityEngine.Events.Unityaction vs System.Action?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What is the difference between UnityEngine.Events.Unityaction vs System.Action.

Can i use System.Action in Unity?

Can i use lambda as UnityAction?

Comment: The type looks the same by looking at their declaration: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityAction.html and https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-is-unityaction-different-from-nets-built-in-action.288873/

Comment: @Draco18s the data link you have sent was great. recommended to anyone who reached to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both questions. For example, these two lines of code are formally the same:

`System.Action<GameObject> myaction = (gameobj) => { Debug.Log(gameobj.name); } ;`

`UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction<GameObject> myaction = (gameobj) => { Debug.Log(gameobj.name); } ;`